Ubuntu Snap Package Remembers Previous Accounts Even After --purge
I want to completely remove a snap package and all configuration.
I have used the below commands, yet after removing the app, when I re-install the package, it STILL remembers me and suggests some of my old accounts to log in with.
sudo snap remove --purge skype
sudo rm -rf /var/snap/skype
sudo rm -rf /var/snap/common/skype
How do I get Snap package to forget previously configured accounts? I have grepped and there are no files containing skype after uninstalling. What am I missing here? Already tried suggestions here: How to remove Skype?

which package are you referring to as that may be significant in finding a solution

This question is similar to: How to remove Skype?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, it's not helpful to my issue. There are no files whatsoever related to this package after removing and purging, yet it still remembers old accounts after re-installing.

Linux is simply based on files - nothing more. There's no magic beyond that. If the file doesn't exist, there's no way of the system "remembering" anything. Just carefully and completely  follow the advice given

You did not give the name of the snap app you removed so this will be a generic answer.
In your home directory is the .snap directory. In that directory is the directory for the app in question.
After purge of the app and before installing it again you need to remove the app directory under the .snap directory in your home directory.

Yes, that directory is gone after running sudo snap remove --purge package_name but issue persists.

You probably removed the snap before without the --purge-option, so a snapshot of the user-data has been saved at that time.
Using the purge-option later on prevented a new snapshot but didn't remove the previously saved snapshot.
Snapshots of user-data are stored in /var/lib/snapd/snapshots, you need root-privileges to access this folder.
Best to check with
snap saved

for existing snapshots, use
snap forget #

to remove a certain snapshot. Example:
~$ snap saved
Set  Snap  Age    Version    Rev  Size    Notes
4    wire  14.8d  3.24.2939  237   982kB  -
~$ snap forget 4
Snapshot #4 forgotten.
~$ snap saved
No snapshots found.


I already tried removing all snapshots and that didn't resolve the issue: https://www.debugpoint.com/clean-up-snap/

@ubuntu_user So did you run the commands I suggested at all? The link you provided didn't mention these commands.
